# Insert the query to three tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I have 3 tables: 'news', 'requirements', 'conditions'. News - basic table. requirements and conditions dependency from 'news' through the consolidated (news_mechanic). How to insert data into all tables at once with a single query. I know, i must use trigger. But, how to do it?

```
CREATE TABLE news (id_news SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, text_news VARCHAR NULL, date_created date NULL).
CREATE TABLE conditions (id, gender_men boolean NULL, gender_women boolean NULL, age_from INTEGER NULL, age_to INTEGER NULL, etc).
CREATE TABLE requirements (id, name VARCHAR, mechanic_test, mechanic_cunsultation, etc).
```

Comment: And news_mechanic. 
`CREATE TABLE news_mechanic (id_news INTEGER, id_requirements INTEGER, id_conditions INTEGER)`

Comment: There are many ways to do it ? such has have a procedure with a BEGIN TRANSACTION, or put a trigger on table After insert, Can you show what you have tried so far ? Thanks

Comment: If it should be all or nothing, it should be inserted in same transaction. There is no command to insert to 3 tables. Trigger is not mandatory, can be stored procedure or just INSERT statements

Comment: @igr: yes you can insert into multiple tables using a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use CTEs:

```
with news_i as (
      insert into news( . . . )
          . . .
          returning (*)
     ),
     conditions_i as (
      insert into conditions ( . . . )
          . . . 
          returning (*)
     )
insert into requirements ( . . . )
    . . .;
```

Each CTE returns the values being inserted, so they can be used in later logic in the query.  I don't see foreign key relationships in your data model, so I don't know if you need data from one table in the others.

Comment: missing from-clause entry for table
I have this error.  I'm trying to contact new.id. 
`.... INSERT INTO requirements VALUES (news.id, conditions.id)`